# Eigenvalue problem with non homogeneous Robin boundary

Tags: elliptic-pde, eigenvalues

I am interested in the eigenvalue problem
$$
\left\lbrace \begin{array}{ll}-\Delta u=\lambda u\textrm{ in }\Omega,\\\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}+\alpha u=g\textrm{ on }\partial\Omega. \end{array}\right.
$$
Of course, one can suppose that the boundary is smooth, the function $g$ is also "good" enough.

I tried to find references, but I did not find anything. If possible, can anyone give me references?

Comment: As stated, this is pretty straightforward. There is a unique solution as long as $\lambda$ is NOT an eigenvalue of the homogeneous problem. The problem becomes more interesting if there is a constraint on the norm of $u$. Such problems are known as "inhomogeneous eigenvalue problems." There is some literature on those, but not very much.